# Need help from someone who understands servers, and downloading files in c#

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, download, server

Let me start by describing what I want to do:
I have a Unity app, and I code it in c#. 
In the app I want to download a file from a server, so I am using HttpWebRequest.

I sent out a HEAD request first to see if the file on the device needs to be updated or not, and to see the file size on the server. If the file needs to be updated I download it.

The class that I use for the downloads is [in this git.](https://github.com/gszauer/Unity-PartialDownload)

Now my problem is I don't know how to host the files because of the following issues:

I tried hosting it on a site with direct download links like ge.tt, but it does not support the HEAD request.

I tried hosting it on a free web host (000webhost), but the download gets stuck most of the time (for large files).

I tried hosting it on Dropbox but the function webRequest.EndGetResponse never returns.

I think the best solution would be to host the files on my computer, but I dont know how to do that, or how to get a download link that will work outside of my lan.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas you have, and answer questions about the code.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll be better off hosting your files in dedicated storage, something like Azure storage (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/) or Amazon's S3. You can't reliably host a file for download by clients (people running the game) from your personal computer - there are too many network considerations and "real world" restrictions (like what happens when your computer is turned off or crashes? what about someone sneaking into your personal files from botched configurations?). Also those cloud based hosting providers will support HEAD requests to do what you want.

Comment: Thank dylan! I ended up using all of your suggestions and using azure, sending a HEAD request and downloading with WebClient. Thanks again!

Comment: Do not use HttpWebRequest for any reason ever. Just use "www"

It couldn't be easier

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html